# Does the Gmail API support JWT?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, jwt, gmail-api

I want to access the Gmail API using NodeJS.

I'm using a server-to-server approach (see [this](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount)) but when I execute the code below, I get a backEndError, code 500 from the Google API.

Any ideas?

```
var authClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    'email',
    'key.pem',
    // Contents of private_key.pem if you want to load the pem file yourself
    // (do not use the path parameter above if using this param)
    'key',
    // Scopes can be specified either as an array or as a single, space-delimited string
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
);

authClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
    if (err) 
        console.log(err);

    gmail.users.messages.list({ userId: 'me', auth: authClient }, function(err, resp) {
    // handle err and response
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: +1 for good question. I don't know, I would walk through https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login for 2nd time and review if all the steps are as expected (this part is not visible in your code). One case when this would probably fail is if the 'me' account uses two-step authentication. In that case software agents need to use special tokens created only for them by 'me' (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/help/faq/auth#what_twostep)

Comment: I'm also trying to use JWT but get `access_denied Requested client not authorized.`

Comment: May I ask you about parameters you given to `new google.auth.JWT` ? I used `key.client_email` as my first parameter, `null` as second, `key.private_key` as third and  then scopes. Where do I tell it from which user should I fetch mails? I need to fetch emails from various accounts inside domain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have the same problem. If I use the scope "https://mail.google.com", I get

```
403
{
  "error" : "access_denied",
  "error_description" : "Requested client not authorized."
}
```

And if I use the scope "https://mail.google.com/" (notice the / at the end), I get

```
403
 'Forbidden'
```

It seems to be related to using JWT and service account.